# Could not able to change the very first commit message

Tags: git, commit

I want to change the very first commit message

```
$ git log --oneline
dfdbdf9 (HEAD -> master) databse changed and user post route created
aa29809 user model created
d8216e4 initial express server with route fies
```

How do I change the commit message with d8216e4 commit hast (very first).

I have tried

`git  rebase -i HEAD~3`

but it shows something like this

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream 'HEAD~3'
```

Also , on using HEAD~1 or HEAD~2 , all git messages except the very first one are ediatbale

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rebase+the+first+commit

Answer (score 0):

Your repository has just three commits: `HEAD`, `HEAD~1` and `HEAD~2`. There is no commit `HEAD~3`, hence the error.

You need to run `git rebase -i --root`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git rebase --root -i`. From the manual:

```
   --root
       Rebase all commits reachable from <branch>, instead of limiting
       them with an <upstream>. This allows you to rebase the root
       commit(s) on a branch. When used with --onto, it will skip changes
       already contained in <newbase> (instead of <upstream>) whereas
       without --onto it will operate on every change. When used together
       with both --onto and --preserve-merges, all root commits will be
       rewritten to have <newbase> as parent instead.
```